# If the tabs use all images to show text + icon on each tab, then how to add text to to help search engine to find the keywords on the tabs?

Tags: html, css, tabs

Especially each image that contains the text and icon are displayed using `background-image` in CSS (using CSS Sprites), so there is no even `alt` or `title` if the image
had been shown using `<img>`.  So, pure image in this case.  How can actual text be added (or using some other mechanism) for search engines to better index these tabs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd use an 'image replacement technique':

http://www.mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/

Comment: @Madmartigan it's relevant in that it is exactly what we're talking about: having text in the HTML but showing an image instead.

Comment: There's no mention of a need for, or even usage of, a replacement effect in OP's question.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your intent. Replacement !== Rollover. This makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Just use actual relevant text in each element and use `text-indent:-9999em;` to shift it offscreen. This may involve extra styling such as `display:block` on the element if it's normally inline for `text-indent` to work but you'll end up with basic a [CSS image replacement](http://www.google.com/search?q=CSS%20image%20replacement) implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You should absolutely be using text somewhere, at least an alt tag.

Try a something like `<span>Text</span>` with `text-indent:-9999px;`, or any of the other variations of css text hiding/masking.

There may be some merit to adding the `title` attribute to those tabs as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a `<span>` and set its `display` to `none` via CSS, then you can put whatever text in there you like for SEO.

This is done on i.e. `<h3>` tags on the css Zen garden. A number of them use this construct:

```
<h3>
  <span>The Road to Enlightenment</span>
</h3>
```

...where you then give the `<h3>` a CSS `background-image` and set the `<span>`'s display to `none`. You should be able to use the same type of idea for tabs that use images.